# Is there a difference in these two ways of sorting an array of strings by the count of characters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

This code is run on a compiler in a Microsoft Edge browser in case the sorting algorithm of the browser matters.

Solving an algorithm question online and it kept failing a *"Must be valid for any given input"* test case. Looked online and found an answer to the question. In the code I found online, it arranges the strings in an array (named 'ordering') according to their character count by using -

```
ordering = [ 'she', 'lives', 'with', 'him', 'in', 'a', 'small', 'apartment' ];

ordering.sort(function(a,b){return a.length-b.length;})
```

The way I tried to arrange the strings were by (didn't know of the `array.sort()` function before this) -

```
for(var i = 0; i < ordering.length-1; i++){
    for(var j = i+1; j < ordering.length; j++){
        if(ordering[j].length < ordering[i].length){
            temp = ordering[i]; /
            ordering[i] = ordering[j];  
            ordering[j] = temp; 
        }
    }
}
```

But, my code would keep failing the test case but whenever I replace it with the former method the test case is passed. I'm confused as to whether these two behave differently or not.

Comment: That first code won't work. This will: `ordering.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);`.

Comment: I am not convinced the first snippet does what you're saying.

Comment: Yea my bad I just noticed I didn't add the .length function for those strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the array according to the length of the words:

```js
const ordering = [ 'she', 'lives', 'with', 'him', 'in', 'a', 'small', 'apartment' ];

console.log(ordering.sort(function(a,b){return a.length - b.length;})) ;
```

Comment: Yea got that. Didn't notice I didn't add the .length function for each string. Now that's out the way my question still remains. How does the two code snippets behave differently, if they do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code in second way

```js
const ordering = [ 'she', 'lives', 'with', 'him', 'in', 'a', 'small', 'apartment' ];
for (let i = 0; i < ordering.length - 1; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < ordering.length; j++) {
    if (ordering[i].length > ordering[j].length) {
      const temp = ordering[i];
      ordering[i] = ordering[j];
      ordering[j] = temp;
    }
  }
}
console.log(ordering);
```

Comment: I notice you changed the condition of the if block, but the logic is basically the same in the end, isn't it? You've also declared the temp variable as constant each loop so wondering if that means anything?

Comment: Yes logic is basically the same in the end. And declaring the temp variable as a constant using the const keyword inside the if statement does not have any impact on the code's behavior. In this context, temp is just a temporary variable used to store the value of one of the elements being swapped during the sorting process, and its value is reassigned to a new value in each iteration of the loop. or you can keep temp as it is which is mentioned in your code.